# Why can't I create a method to the function who's scope I'm within?

Tags: javascript, methods, javascript-objects

I'm trying to create an object that binds to the global namespace and then create methods within that object referring to itself.  I want all the methods to be created when the object is created, and `obj` is defined, but the method is not (based on the console output at the bottom). Does `return this;` not return the method itself to the call? Or is the problem that I'm calling `this.methd` not correct inside of the obj function?  I'm sorry in advance if this is a duplicate, it didn't seem that the similar questions are like mine overall, close but no cigar.

```
(function(window, undefined){
  var obj = function(){
    this.methd = function() {
      return this;
    };
  }
window.obj = obj;
})(window);

function defined(value) {
  var def = value ? 'pass' : 'fail';
  return def;
}
console.log(defined(obj))
console.log(defined(obj.methd))

//Output:
//pass
//fail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `window.obj` to be a reference to a function.  Until that function runs, `methd` is not defined anywhere, regardless of the contents of that function or what it returns.

If you invoke it as a constructor function to create an instance, `methd` will become defined, but only on *that specific instance*:

```
var b = new obj();
console.log(defined(b.methd)); //pass
```

Alternatively, just invoking the function as a normal function will use the current value of `this` (which is the global object, or `window`) and create the `methd` function on that object:

```
obj();
console.log(defined(window.methd)); //pass
```

Comment: I definitely understand why it doesn't work now, thank you, that essentially answered my question, now I have a new question though, where would I place the 'obj();'?  Adding this did nothing, I included it outside of the obj definition, but inside of the self-evoking function.  The first way worked, but I'm now interested in understanding the second option as well.

Comment: @John I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but functions in JavaScript are objects, and can therefore have properties.  As such, you can directly assign the `methd` function as a property on the `obj` function object [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/zpq5x531/).

Comment: I'm in the beginning stages of creating a widget of sorts that requires the user to only add a single js file to the directory and a script tag to HTML.  And at the time of page load fully establish all features upfront as well as all methods be accessible from any code the user of the script would create in a external script.  Primarily now though, with what you provided me, I was just interested in why adding `obj();` didn't work.